# With AngularJS : Bind a radio button input to a Boolean with possible null value

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS v1.5.0, I am trying to bind a radio input field to a Boolean variable that can be : true, false or null. Using the ng-value directive sets a null value to false.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="true"  ng-change="update()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="false" ng-change="update()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="null"  ng-change="update()">
```

Would you have any idea about how this could be done ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1695) for the `ngValue` directive, you'll notice that it only runs scope.$eval() on values that are true, false or a number.

```
var CONSTANT_VALUE_REGEXP = /^(true|false|\d+)$/;
var ngValueDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 100,
    compile: function(tpl, tplAttr) {
      if (CONSTANT_VALUE_REGEXP.test(tplAttr.ngValue)) {
        return function ngValueConstantLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          attr.$set('value', scope.$eval(attr.ngValue));
        };
      } else {
        return function ngValueLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          scope.$watch(attr.ngValue, function valueWatchAction(value) {
            attr.$set('value', value);
          });
        };
      }
    }
  };
};
```

To overcome this and include null in that group, you would need to write your own directive, or handle converting the value programmatically when the form gets submitted.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in 1.4.9. 1.5.0 and 1.6.3

```
<span ng-init="foo = {value: null}">{{foo}}</span>
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="null" ng-checked="foo.value === null" />Null
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="true" />True
<input type="radio" ng-model="foo.value" ng-value="false" />False
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weblyan/HB7LU/28895/)